# Symmetric quadratic, positive root less than one

Tags: quadratics

I have this "symmetric" quadratic equation:
\begin{align*}
a(1-x)^2+b(1-x)x+c x^2 = 0
\end{align*}
and I am trying to impose conditions on $a,b,c$ such that there is at least one root $0<x_* <1$. In that case, writing $y=1-x$ the equation reads as:
\begin{align*}
a y^2+b(1-y)y+c (1-y)^2 = 0
\end{align*}
(hence the "symmetry"). I expect something like $ac<0$. Any ideas/reference?

\Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be sure there is at least a root between $0$ and $1$ ,By IVT, it is sufficient to have $f (0)f (1)<0$
or $$ac <0$$

Comment: Thank you! I had actually calculated that and obtained the roots in a closed form, but I am unable to impose conditions on $a,b,c$ such that they lie between $0$ and $1$, this is why I was wondering if there is a shorter way, due to the symmetry of the equation!

Comment: Please look now. an other approch.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to deal with this one using the good ol' quadratic formula. First we need to expand your quadratic:
$$a(1−x)^2+b(1−x)x+cx^2=0$$
$$a(x^2-2x+1)+b(x-x^2)+cx^2=0$$
$$ax^2-2ax+a+bx-bx^2+cx^2=0$$
$$(a-b+c)x^2+(b-2a)x+a=0$$
Now we can use the quadratic formula:
$$x=\frac{2a-b\pm \sqrt{(b-2a)^2-4a(a-b+c)}}{2(a-b+c)}$$
You're looking for a zero between $0$ and $1$, so the relationship you're looking for is
$$0<\frac{2a-b\pm \sqrt{(b-2a)^2-4a(a-b+c)}}{2(a-b+c)}<1$$
$$0<2a-b\pm \sqrt{(b-2a)^2-4a(a-b+c)}<2a-2b+2c$$
$$b-2a<\pm \sqrt{(b-2a)^2-4a(a-b+c)}<b+2c$$
$$(b-2a)^2<(b-2a)^2-4a(a-b+c)<(b+2c)^2$$
$$b^2-4ab+4a^2<b^2-4ab+4a-4a^2+4ab-4ac<b^2+4bc+4c^2$$
$$-4ab+4a^2<4a-4a^2-4ac<4bc+4c^2$$
$$a-ab^2<a-a^2-ac<bc+c^2$$
That should be it, but if I made a mistake in my algebra or if I can simplify it further, please let me know.